# Cross validation and Improvement

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, cross-validation

I was wondering how the cross validation process can improve a model. I am totally new to this field and keen to learn.
I understood the principle of cross-validation but don't understand how it improves a model. Let's say the model is divided into 4 folds than if I train my model on the 3 first fourth and test on the last one the model is gonna train well. But when I repeat this step by training the model on the last 3 fourth and test on the first one, most of the training data has already been "reviewed" by the model? The model won't improve with data already seen right? Is it a "mean" of the models made with the different training data sets?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross validation doesn't actually improve the model, but helps you to accurately score it's performance.

Let's say at the beginning of your training you divide your data into 80% train and 20% test sets. Then you train on the said 80% and test on 20% and get the performance metric.

The problem is, when separating the data in the beginning, you did so hopefully randomly, or otherwise arbitrary, and as a result, the model performance you obtained is somehow relying on the pseudo-random number generator you've used or your judgement.

So instead you divide your data into, for example, 5 random equal sets. Then you take set 1, put it aside, train on sets 2-5, test on set 1 and record the performance metric. Then you put aside set 2, and train a fresh (not trained) model on sets 1, 3-5, test on set 2, record the metric and so on.

After 5 sets you will have 5 performance metrics. If you take their average (of the most appropriate kind) it would be a better representation of your model performance, because you are 'averaging out' the random effects of data splitting.

I think it is explained well in this [blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) with some code in Python.

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much that was clear! So in order to use cross validation I need to initialize a new model each time I assess it or it depends on the implementation?

Comment: Yes, you will need to initialize a new model before every of the _k_ runs. The details depend on the implementation, you can be saving every model alongside its score if you want, or you can just overwrite it every time, depends on what you want to get in the end.

Answer (score 0):

With 4-fold cross-validation you are effectively training 4 different models. There's no dependency between the models and one does not train on top of the other.

What will happen later depends on the implementation. Typically you can access all models that were trained and it's left to you what to do with that.

Comment: Thanks! Then how do you explain improvement? And how can I access previous models?

Comment: @CômeSchaeffer I explained to you the general principle behind k-fold cross-validation. You're referring now to some specific implementation that you haven't even mentioned. Most generic answer to your question would be: there's no improvement from model to model, it's just sheer luck. Shuffle many times, aggregate the results and see what comes out. Also, there are no "previous models" in cross-validation. They can be trained in parallel. How to access them? Again depends on the implementation. You haven't shared your code, not even the language you're using.

Comment: Because I'm talking about general knowledge of cross validation not a particular case...

Comment: @CômeSchaeffer You asked "how do I access previous models?" That's asking about specifics of particular implementation, not general.